# How to parse json in Titanium to display data in table view

Tags: javascript, json, titanium, titanium-mobile

Hi i am getting data from remote server. Its connecting successfully and get data.

```
   function getTodoList () {

var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open("GET", "http://192.168.10.109/read_todo_list.php", true);
    client.send();
    client.onreadystatechange = function() {

    **////////Creating Problem here///////**
            var get= console.log(JSON.parse(client.response));

         for( var i=0; i<get.length; i++){
     var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
            title: get[i].todo,
            hasChild : true,
        });     
        dataArray.push(row);                
                 }
           $.tableView.setData(dataArray);

        };
     }
```

In Chrome Console showing data but terminate with error: 
         Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input index.html:1
       Object
       todo: Array[2]
       0: Object
      todo: "Khaleeq Raza"
     **proto**: Object
      1: Object
      todo: "Ateeq Raza"
     **proto**: Object
    length: 2
    **proto**: Array[0]
   **proto**: Object
    VM86:10
    Object
    VM86:10
      Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Please help with thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    client.onreadystatechange = function() {

        var get=JSON.parse(client.responseText);

     for( var i=0; i<get.length; i++){
 var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        title: get[i].todo,
        hasChild : true,
    });     
    dataArray.push(row);                
             }
       $.tableView.setData(dataArray);

    };
```